# If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1$, find Min $P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c+ab}}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality, uvw

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1$. Find Minimum of $P$: $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c+ab}}$$ The source of the problem is unknown.

Here is my attempt:

We have: $$P^2=\frac{1}{2a+bc}+\frac{1}{2b+ca}+\frac{1}{2c+ab}+2\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2a+bc)(2b+ca)}}$$
I proved 2 inequalities: $$\frac{1}{2a+bc}+\frac{1}{2b+ca}+\frac{1}{2c+ab}\ge 2 (1)$$
and: $$\frac{\sqrt{2a+bc}+\sqrt{2b+ca}+\sqrt{2c+ab}}{\sqrt{(2a+bc)(2b+ca)(2c+ab)}}\ge \frac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}(2)$$

1. Prove (1):
   $$\frac{1}{2a+bc}+\frac{1}{2b+ca}+\frac{1}{2c+ab}\ge 2$$
   $$\iff f(r)=2r^2+r(4p^2-17p+14)+2(2-p)\le 0 (*)$$
   which: $$f^{'}(r)=4r+4p^2-17p+14$$

$\bullet:\sqrt{3}\le p\le 2$ which implies: $ r\le \dfrac{p}{9}\implies f^{'}(r)<  4p^2-\dfrac{149}{9}p+14 =(p-2.95)(p-1.18)<0$

Hence, $f(r)$ is decreasing when $\sqrt{3}\le p\le 2$ and using Schur inequality: $r\ge \dfrac{p(4-p^2)}{9} $, it leads to:
$$f(r)\le f\left(\frac{p(4-p^2)}{9}\right)=2p^6-32p^5+137p^4+18p^3-580p^2+342p+324$$
$$=(p-2)\left((p-2)(2p^4-28p^3+17p^2+198p+144)+126\right)<0$$

$\bullet: 2\le p\le 4$, we rewrite (*) as:
$$ f(r)=-2r^2-r(4p^2-17p+14)+2(p-2)\ge 0$$
Hence:
$$ f^{''}(r)=-4<0\implies min f(r)=min \{f(0);f\left(\frac{1}{3p}\right)\}$$
Calculating:
$$f(0)=2(p-2)\ge 0$$
$$f\left(\frac{1}{3p}\right)=\frac{-2}{9p^2}-\frac{4p^2-17p+14}{3p}+2(p-2)\ge \frac{11}{8}>0$$

2. Prove (2):

Squaring both side (2), we will prove: $$2(a+b+c)+1+2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(2a+bc)(2b+ca)}\ge \left(\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2(2a+bc)(2b+ca)(2c+ab) $$

It seems complicated for me to full proof.
Am I on right approach ? If you find any mistake, please tell me why.
I also thought of Holder inequality, which gives: $$P^2.\sum_{cyc}(2a+bc)(mb+nc)^3\ge ((m+n)(a+b+c))^3$$
Hope to see more ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+bc}\geq2$ we can prove by $uvw$ directly.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $$f(w^3)=-2w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)$$ and we see that $f$ is a concave function,

which says it's enough to prove the last inequality in two following cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Let $c=0$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+bc}=\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{1}{ab}=\frac{a+b}{2}+1\geq2;$$
2. Two variables are equal.

Let $b=a$. Thus, $c=\frac{1-a^2}{2a},$ where $0<a\leq1$ and we need to prove that
$$(1-a)(2-5a-a^2+8a^3-2a^4)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$2-5a-a^2+8a^3-2a^4=$$
$$=\frac{2}{25}(5a-3)^2a(1-a)+\frac{1}{25}(90a^3+53a^2-143a+50)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{25}\left(90a^3+53a^2+3\cdot\frac{50}{3}-143a\right)\geq\frac{a}{25}\left(5\sqrt[5]{90\cdot53\cdot\left(\frac{50}{3}\right)^3}-143\right)>0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2a+bc)(2b+ac)}}\geq\frac{1+2\sqrt2}{2},$$ which is hard.

For example, Holder with $\left((2\sqrt2-1)a+b+c\right)^3,$ which saves the case of an equality occurring, leads to a wrong inequality.

I think, the following Holder can help.

Let $ab=z^2$, $ac=y^2$ and $bc=x^2$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Thus, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2xy-x\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}\right)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^3}}\geq\sqrt2+1,$$
where the last inequality seems true and from here we can get a polynomial inequality.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. So we just need to prove (2), right ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang Yes. Maybe it's better to work with the starting inequality.

Comment: I agree with you, is there Holder proof for OP ? I saw you mentioned ((2√2−1)a+b+c)^3. Did you try it for (2) ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang Yes, I tried it for $(2).$ Also, I don't see how Holder can help for the starting  inequality.

Comment: This simple form is very hard.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+ab}}\ge 3$$ dear Michael Rozenberg, could you share solution to us? Thank you

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang Now I don't remember, how I solved it. I am ready to do it again. Post this problem, Maybe someone will find a solution before me.

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang I think, it should be $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+bc}}\geq2\sqrt2.$

Comment: thank you for refinement. It occurs when two of of them be to infinity

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang One of them be infinity.

Comment: yes. One of them be infinity, two of of them be zero. It reminds me Phạm Kim Hung's inequality.

Comment: I found a problem :https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1842153p12384715, which mixing variables works well.  Does it work for main problem ?

Comment: have you tried Holder with $\sum_{cyc}(2a+bc)(xb+yc)^3(ma+nb+nc)^3 $ ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang No. In any case it would be very ugly.

Comment: sorry if I made something wrong. When I read gain your solution, there is a little point which you say $f(w^3)$ is concave function. As I search in the internet, $f''(w^3)=-2<0$ which say that it is convex function. Thank you if you could explain more to me, my knowledge is not good enough.

Comment: I think you write a typo. We should use Holder with $((\sqrt{2}-1)a+b+c)^3$ ?

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang I mean the following Holder: $\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2a+bc)(2b+ac)}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a+bc)(2b+ac)(kc+a+b)^3\geq(k+2)^3(a+b+c)^3.$ Easy to see that $k=2\sqrt2-1$ saves the case of occurring equality .

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=3352055088345343&set=pcb.3352057378345114

Comment: Can downvoter explain me your step?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 nice solutions for
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{2a+bc} \ge 2.$$

Solution 1:

By AM-GM
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{2a+bc} \ge \sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a}{b+c}+a(b+c)+bc} =\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{b+c}{a+b+c}=2.$$
Equality holds iff $a=b=1, c=0$ and per.

Solution 2:

By C-S
$$\dfrac{1}{b+c}+\dfrac{a^2}{a} \ge \dfrac{(a+1)^2}{a+b+c}, \ \forall a>0, \;bc \ge 0,$$
or
$$\dfrac{1}{b+c}\ge \dfrac{(a+1)^2}{a+b+c}-a=\dfrac{2a+1-ab-ca}{a+b+c}=\dfrac{2a+bc}{a+b+c}, \ \forall a,b,c \ge 0.$$
So
$$\dfrac{1}{2a+bc} \ge \dfrac{b+c}{a+b+c}.$$
And the rest is easy.

Comment: Very elegant idea ! Does it work for $$\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{1}{b+ca}+\frac{1}{c+ab}\ge 3$$ $$\frac{1}{3a+bc}+\frac{1}{3b+ca}+\frac{1}{3c+ab}\ge \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{9+\sqrt{3}}$$ with same condition ?

Comment: I think it doesn't work.