# Proving $\sum\limits_{cyc} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}} \ge 1+\sqrt{2}$ for $a,b,c \ge 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c \ge 0 : ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2b+ca}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2c+ab}} \ge 1+\sqrt{2}.$$

Source: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u806299h2781273p24423975).
and [here] [If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1$, find Min $P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b+ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c+ab}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703001/if-a-b-c-ge-0-abbcca-1-find-min-p-frac1-sqrt2abc-frac1-sqrt2).

I tried Holder, or AM-GM, Cauchy - Schwarz but it is not good.

And this is an old Problem, it's easier.

> Let $a,b,c \ge 0 : ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\dfrac{1}{2a+bc}+\dfrac{1}{2b+ca}+\dfrac{1}{2c+ab} \ge 2.$$

By AM-GM
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{2a+bc} \ge \sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a}{b+c}+a(b+c)+ca} =\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{b+c}{a+b+c}=2.$$

I hope this problem will be solved by a nice solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My second proof using Holder inequality*.

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a + bc}}\right)^2 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (2a + bc)(2ab + 2bc + 2ca + b\sqrt 2 + c\sqrt 2)^3\\
 \ge{}& \left(6ab + 6bc + 6ca + 2a\sqrt 2 + 2b\sqrt{2} + 2c\sqrt{2}\right)^3. 
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(6ab + 6bc + 6ca + 2a\sqrt 2 + 2b\sqrt{2} + 2c\sqrt{2}\right)^3\\
 \ge{}& (1 + \sqrt 2)^2\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (2a + bc)(2ab + 2bc + 2ca + b\sqrt 2 + c\sqrt 2)^3. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$. Using $p^2 \ge 3q = 3$, we have $p \ge \sqrt 3$.

(1) is written as
$$c_1 r + c_0 \ge 0\tag{2}$$
where
\begin{align*}
  c_1 &=  42\,\sqrt {2}{p}^{2}+60\,\sqrt {2}p+56\,{p}^{2}-48\,\sqrt {2}+
 100\,p-88, \\
 c_0 &= 10\,\sqrt {2}{p}^{3}-36\,\sqrt {2}{p}^{2}-8\,{p}^{
  3}+100\,\sqrt {2}p+92\,{p}^{2}-136\,\sqrt {2}-168\,p+32.
\end{align*}
We have $c_1 \ge 0.$

If $p^2 \ge 4q = 4$, we have $c_0 \ge 0$. Thus, (2) is true.

If $p^2 < 4q = 4$, using degree three Schur $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} = \frac{4p - p^3}{9}$, we have
$$c_1r + c_0 \ge c_1 \cdot \frac{4p - p^3}{9} + c_0 \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: The Holder using is amazing!

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, it is powerful.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof**.

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: $a \ge 2$

By AM-GM, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a + bc}} = \frac{4}{2\sqrt{(2a + bc)\cdot 4}} \ge \frac{4}{2a + bc + 4}$,
and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b + ca}} = \frac{2}{2\sqrt{(2b + ca)\cdot 1}}
\ge \frac{2}{2b + ca + 1}$, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c + ab}}
= \frac{2}{2\sqrt{(2c + ab)\cdot 1}} \ge \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1}$. By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{2}{2b + ca + 1} + \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1}
\ge \frac{8}{2b + ca + 1 + 2c + ab + 1}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{4}{2a + bc + 4} + \frac{8}{2b + ca + 1 + 2c + ab + 1} \ge \frac52 > 1 + \sqrt 2. \tag{1}$$
(1) is true. The proof is given at the end.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case 2**: $a < 2$

By AM-GM, we have
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a + bc}} = \frac{2\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt{(2a+bc)\cdot 2}} \ge \frac{2\sqrt 2}{2a + bc + 2}$
and
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b + ca}} = \frac{2\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt{(2b+ca)\cdot 2}} \ge \frac{2\sqrt 2}{2b + ca + 2}$
and
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c+ab}}
= \frac{2}{2\sqrt{(2c+ab)\cdot 1}} \ge \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1}$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2\sqrt 2}{2a + bc + 2} + \frac{2\sqrt 2}{2b + ca + 2} + \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1} \ge 1 + \sqrt 2$$
or
$$\frac{4 - 4ab - abc^2 - 2a^2c - 2b^2c}{(2a + bc + 2)(2b + ca + 2)}\cdot\sqrt 2 + \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1} - 1 \ge 0. \tag{2}$$

Using $b, c \le 1$, we have $4 - 4ab - abc^2 - 2a^2c - 2b^2c
\ge 4(bc + ca) - abc - 2a^2 c - 2bc = c(2-a)(2a + b) \ge 0$. Using $\sqrt 2 > 7/5$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{4 - 4ab - abc^2 - 2a^2c - 2b^2c}{(2a + bc + 2)(2b + ca + 2)}\cdot\frac75 + \frac{2}{2c + ab + 1} - 1 \ge 0. \tag{3}$$
(3) is true. The proof is given at the end.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of (1)*:

Let $p = b + c, q = bc$.

From $ab + bc + ca = 1$, we have $ap + q = 1$
which results in $a = \frac{1 - q}{p}$.
From $a \ge 2$, we have $q \le 1 - 2p$.

Thus, we have
$$0 < p \le 1/2, \quad 0 \le q \le 1 - 2p. $$

(1) is written as
$$f(q) := - \left( 10-5\,p \right) {q}^{2}+ \left( -10\,{p}^{2}+33\,p+8 \right) 
q+2\, \left( 6\,p+1 \right)  \left( 1-2\,p \right)\ge 0. 
$$

Since $0 < p \le 1/2$, $f(q)$ is concave.
We have $f(0) \ge 0$ and $f(1 - 2p)
= 10p(1 - 2p)(7 - 2p)\ge 0$.
Thus, $f(q) \ge 0$ for all $0 \le q \le 1 - 2p$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of (3)*:

Using $c = \frac{1 - ab}{a + b}$, after simplifying (3), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &6\,{a}^{4}{b}^{3}+6\,{a}^{3}{b}^{4}-12\,{a}^{5}b-24\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}-36
 \,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}-24\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}-12\,a{b}^{5}+43\,{a}^{4}b\\
 &\quad +76\,{a}^
 {3}{b}^{2}+76\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}+43\,a{b}^{4}+8\,{a}^{4}-2\,{a}^{3}b+4\,{
  a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,a{b}^{3}+8\,{b}^{4}\\
 &\quad -15\,{a}^{3}+2\,{a}^{2}b+2\,a{b}^{
  2}-15\,{b}^{3}-2\,{a}^{2}-16\,ab-2\,{b}^{2}\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{4}
\end{align*}

From $2 > a \ge b \ge c\ge 0$ and $ab + bc + ca = 1$,
we have
$$0 < b \le 1, \quad \frac{1}{3b} \le a < 2. \tag{5}$$

Let
$$s = \frac{1}{b} - 1, \quad t = \frac{a - \frac{1}{3b}}{2 - a}.$$ Then $s, t \ge 0$
and
$$b = \frac{1}{1 + s}, \quad a = \frac{1}{3b}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + t} + \frac{2t}{1 + t}. \tag{6}$$

Using (6), (4) is written as
$$\frac{1}{81(1 + t)^5(1 + s)^5}f(s, t)\ge 0$$
where $f(s, t)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.

We are done.

Comment: By AM-GM : $(2-bc)(2a+bc)\le (a+1)^2,$ hence $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{2-bc}}{a+1}.$$Interestingly, the stronger inequality$$\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2-bc}}{a+1}+\frac{\sqrt{2-ca}}{b+1}+\frac{\sqrt{2-ab}}{c+1}\ge 1+\sqrt{2}, \forall a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1.}$$is also true and very hard. Equality holds iff: one of $a,b,c$ is zero.