# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}}\ge 6$ for $a, b, c \ge 0$ with $ab+bc+ca=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, holder-inequality

> **Problem.** Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that
> $$\frac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}}+\frac{4b+1}{\sqrt{4b+ca}}+\frac{4c+1}{\sqrt{4c+ab}}\ge 6.$$

---

I've tried to use Holder inequality without success.

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(4a+bc)(4a+1)\ge [4(a+b+c)+3]^3. \tag{1}$$

$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(4a+bc)(4a+1)(b+c)^3\ge \left(\sum_{cyc}(4a+1)(b+c)\right)^3.\tag{2} $$

Which is both leads to wrong inequality in general.

> I'd like to ask two question.

1. **Is there a better Holder using ?**

I think the appropriate one might be ugly but if you find it, please free share it here.

2. **Is there others idea which is smooth enough?**

For example, Mixing variables, AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz...etc.

I aslo hope to see a good lower bound of $\dfrac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}},$ which eliminate the radical form (may be the rest is simpler by $uvw$)

All idea and comment is welcome. Thank you for interest!

*Remark.* About $uvw$, see [here.][1]

Updated edit: The RiverLi's Holder using is impressed. If someone found other approach, please share it here.
[1]: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**.

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{4a + 1}{\sqrt{4a + bc}}\right)^2 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4a + 1)(4a + bc)(ab + 6bc + 3ca + a + 4b + 2c)^3\\
 \ge{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4a + 1)(ab + 6bc + 3ca + a + 4b + 2c)\right)^3. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4a + 1)(ab + 6bc + 3ca + a + 4b + 2c)\right)^3\\
 \ge{}& 36\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4a + 1)(4a + bc)(ab + 6bc + 3ca + a + 4b + 2c)^3. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

(2) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the yield $ab+6bc+3ca+a+4b+2c$ ? It seems unsual for a symmetrical inequality.

Comment: @TATAbox Try and error. I first tried $p_1a + p_2b + p_3c$ but failed. Then I tried $p_1a + p_2b + p_3 c + p_4ab + p_5bc + p_6ca$ and works.

Comment: @TATAbox Perhaps there are other forms?

Comment: I really hope see it. Btw, did you try the substitution $x=(4a+1)/\sqrt{4a+bc};...$ and find relatives between yields $x^2+y^2+z^2,x^2y^2z^2$ ? I believe it works in some way

Comment: @TATAbox I did not try.

Comment: @TATAbox Did you try $\frac{4a+1}{\sqrt{4a+bc}} \ge \frac{4a+1}{\frac{4a+bc}{2x} + \frac{x}{2}}$ for some $x = x(a, b, c)$?

Comment: it is a nice idea. I'll try. Your idea is helpful for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703001/if-a-b-c-ge-0-abbcca-1-find-min-p-frac1-sqrt2abc-frac1-sqrt2

Comment: @TATAbox I mean something like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740147/prove-frac1-sqrt5a4-frac1-sqrt5b4-frac1-sqrt5c4-geq1-f/4740643#4740643

Comment: @TATAbox By the way, do you have a nice proof of this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708624/proving-sum-limits-cyc-dfrac1-sqrt2abc-ge-1-sqrt2-for-a-b-c-g/4756962#4756962

Comment: There are several proofs with a bit of calculating work

Comment: @TATAbox I just found a proof using Holder. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708624/proving-sum-limits-cyc-dfrac1-sqrt2abc-ge-1-sqrt2-for-a-b-c-g/4770110#4770110

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a+bc}}\ge \frac{2\left((\sqrt{2}-1)a+1\right)}{\left( 3-2\sqrt{2} \right) a^2+2\sqrt{2}a+bc+1},$ also helps

Comment: @TATAbox It is nice!

Comment: I still can not find a simple Holder using.

Comment: @TATAbox I used quadratic. Perhaps no simpler than quadratic. By the way, the expression after Holder is not simple by hand.

Comment: Did you try to use Holder for the problem I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782823/if-abbcca-1-prove-frac-sqrta1abc-frac-sqrtb1bca-frac-s?noredirect=1#comment10167721_4782823 ?

Comment: @TATAbox I don't have a nice proof.

Comment: Does it mean that you found Holder using?

Comment: @TATAbox No. I have not tried Holder yet.

Comment: After a long time think of the problem, I accepted your answer.

Comment: @TATAbox Hope to see nice proof.